# python 2 vs python 3 columns ordering using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, pandas

I am facing an issue related to column ordering in pandas data frame while saving it as csv. This is the ordering in python 3:

[image]

while in python 2 , it reverts the columns and also if the number of column is larger than 2 the ordering is totally different

[image]

here is the code where i save data frame as csv :

```
selective_price = []
for index_sample, row_sample in selectivePriceList.iterrows():
    selective_price.append(row_sample.loc[list_keys])
    counter +=1
    #print(selective_price)  
selective_price = pd.concat(selective_price, axis=1) 
selective_price = selective_price.transpose()
selective_price.insert(0, "Date", DateFrame.loc[index:index+(w-1)], allow_duplicates=False)
#print(selective_price)
start_end_date = str(DateFrame[index]) + "_" + str(DateFrame[index+(w-1)])
#print (start_end_date)
selective_price = selective_price.sort_values(by=['Date'])
print (selective_price.columns)
selective_price.to_csv('rolling_results_'+start_end_date+"_.csv",index=False)
```

when using `selective_price = selective_price.sort_index().transpose()` , the columns are sorted alphabetically not with the correct index

[image]

while the correct index must be 
[image]

Comment: Does `print (selective_price.columns)` print different results in Python2 vs Python3?

Comment: `Index([u'Date', u'litecoin', u'bitcoin'], dtype='object')` python2 and `Index(['Date', 'bitcoin', 'litecoin'], dtype='object')` python3

Comment: I think that explains it

Comment: So, hope i can solve this

Comment: What do You think might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you transpose the DataFrame here:

```
selective_price = selective_price.transpose()
```

The original index becomes the new column names, so you can simply sort first:

```
selective_price = selective_price.sort_index().transpose()
```

Now the column names will be sorted regardless of Python version.

Probably the reason this happened in the first place is you load your data from a `dict` which has no ordering.

Comment: if it more than 2 column the results are not ordered correctly as , this sort them alphabetically
i have edited the question regarding this point

Comment: If you want a specific order, then do `selectice_price[['bitcoin', 'litecoin', ...]]` with whatever order you want after transpose.